# How to create physical circle in JS?

Tags: javascript

I suppose there are 5 circles in my div or canvas. I hope they are moving randomly on the screen. When they hit each other or the borders they are bounced away. How to achieve this effect? Are there any sample code or snippet? Cheers!

Comment: the concept is "collision detection"

Comment: Some code snippets http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589497(v=vs.85).aspx